# Terminate Akka-Http Web Socket connection asynchronously

Tags: scala, websocket, akka-stream, akka-http

Web Socket connections in Akka Http are treated as an Akka Streams `Flow`. This seems like it works great for basic request-reply, but it gets more complex when messages should also be pushed out over the websocket. The core of my server looks kind of like:

```
lazy val authSuccessMessage = Source.fromFuture(someApiCall)

lazy val messageFlow = requestResponseFlow
    .merge(updateBroadcastEventSource)

lazy val handler = codec
  .atop(authGate(authSuccessMessage))
  .join(messageFlow)

handleWebSocketMessages {
  handler
}
```

Here, `codec` is a (de)serialization `BidiFlow` and `authGate` is a `BidiFlow` that processes an authorization message and prevents outflow of any messages until authorization succeeds. Upon success, it sends `authSuccessMessage` as a reply. `requestResponseFlow` is the standard request-reply pattern, and `updateBroadcastEventSource` mixes in async push messages.

I want to be able to send an error message and terminate the connection gracefully in certain situations, such as bad authorization, `someApiCall` failing, or a bad request processed by `requestResponseFlow`. So basically, basically it seems like I want to be able to asynchronously complete `messageFlow` with one final message, even though its other constituent flows are still alive.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to do this using a [`KillSwitch`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.4/#akka.stream.KillSwitch).

**Updated version**

The old version had the problem that it didn't seem to work when triggered by a `BidiFlow` stage higher up in the stack (such as my `authGate`). I'm not sure exactly why, but modeling the shutoff as a `BidiFlow` itself, placed further up the stack, resolved the issue.

```
val shutoffPromise = Promise[Option[OutgoingWebsocketEvent]]()

/**
 * Shutoff valve for the connection. It is triggered when `shutoffPromise`
 * completes, and sends a final optional termination message if that
 * promise resolves with one.
 */
val shutoffBidi = {
  val terminationMessageSource = Source
    .maybe[OutgoingWebsocketEvent]
    .mapMaterializedValue(_.completeWith(shutoffPromise.future))

  val terminationMessageBidi = BidiFlow.fromFlows(
    Flow[IncomingWebsocketEventOrAuthorize],
    Flow[OutgoingWebsocketEvent].merge(terminationMessageSource)
  )

  val terminator = BidiFlow
    .fromGraph(KillSwitches.singleBidi[IncomingWebsocketEventOrAuthorize, OutgoingWebsocketEvent])
    .mapMaterializedValue { killSwitch =>
      shutoffPromise.future.foreach { _ => println("Shutting down connection"); killSwitch.shutdown() }
    }

  terminationMessageBidi.atop(terminator)
}
```

Then I apply it just inside the `codec`:

```
val handler = codec
  .atop(shutoffBidi)
  .atop(authGate(authSuccessMessage))
  .join(messageFlow)
```

**Old version**

```
val shutoffPromise = Promise[Option[OutgoingWebsocketEvent]]()

/**
 * Shutoff valve for the flow of outgoing messages. It is triggered when
 * `shutoffPromise` completes, and sends a final optional termination
 * message if that promise resolves with one.
 */
val shutoffFlow = {
  val terminationMessageSource = Source
    .maybe[OutgoingWebsocketEvent]
    .mapMaterializedValue(_.completeWith(shutoffPromise.future))

  Flow
    .fromGraph(KillSwitches.single[OutgoingWebsocketEvent])
    .mapMaterializedValue { killSwitch =>
      shutoffPromise.future.foreach(_ => killSwitch.shutdown())
    }
    .merge(terminationMessageSource)
}
```

Then `handler` looks like:

```
val handler = codec
  .atop(authGate(authSuccessMessage))
  .join(messageFlow via shutoffFlow)
```

Comment: If I may ask, why's shutoffPromise a lazy val?

Comment: @ViktorKlang I have my whole web socket handler within a `case class` and I was having crashes due to initialization order, and I didn't want to worry about it.

Comment: Sure, but for this example it isn't needed. :)

Comment: Fair point, I more or less just cut-and-pasted what worked for me. But it's a non-compiling fragment anyway, so may as well simplify.